# Orchard Exception

Tags: orchardcms

After a few days running our Orchard CMS homepage our site went offline. A site restart was not sufficient. I had to restart/recycle the application pool. Then the site was running again. The error log shows the following message.
I have my Orchard site running on a network mapping. So I think such an error could happen after connection interrupt to the network drive?

```
2014-09-09 01:39:29,260 [8] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default
 (null)
System.ArgumentException: Ein Element mit dem gleichen Schlüssel wurde bereits hinzugefügt.
   bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   bei Orchard.Data.Conventions.RecordTableNameConvention..ctor(IEnumerable`1 descriptors)
   bei Orchard.Data.Providers.AbstractDataServicesProvider.CreatePersistenceModel(ICollection`1 recordDescriptors)
   bei Orchard.Data.Providers.AbstractDataServicesProvider.BuildConfiguration(SessionFactoryParameters parameters)
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.<>c__DisplayClass5.<BuildConfiguration>b__2()
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionConfigurationCache.GetConfiguration(Func`1 builder)
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildConfiguration()
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetConfiguration()
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.Demand()
   bei Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.For(Type entityType)
   bei Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
   bei Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
   bei Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings settings)
   bei Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.<CreateAndActivateShells>b__7(ShellSettings settings)
2014-09-09 01:39:29,979 [8] Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost - (null) - A tenant could not be started: Default
 (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just found out it is actually a server farm. It is not synced sometimes. So I guess this is the cause. The error message would match then, as it tries to add a key that has been added already. When the two fileservers are not synchronised it is random what you get and to which instance you are talking.